# MOSFET - Derivation of I/V Characteristics - Small Vds

Tags: mosfet

I'm following Razavi's CMOS Analogue IC design book and I'm having some trouble how he did an approximation.

He did the following

[image]

My question is - how did he come up with that condition of V_DS being less than 2 times (Vgs - Vth). I saw a brief explanation in one of his videos but it didn't make much sense to me. I know this equation is applicable when Vds is small and he just quantified how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just some math:

\$I_D=k[v_{ov}v_{ds}-\frac{1}{2}v_{ds}^2] \$

\$ \ \  \ \ \ =\frac{1}{2}k.v_{ds}[2v_{ov}-v_{ds}] \$

Assuming the MOSFET in deep triode region, and 2v_ov >> vds, the expression for ID becomes,

\$I_D=\frac{1}{2}k.v_{ds}2v_{ov}\$

\$ \ \ \ \ =k.v_{ds}v_{ov}\$

Here \$v_{ov}=v_{gs} - v_{th}\$ and \$k=\mu _nc_{ox}w/l\$. The assumption 2v_ov >> vds has to be satisfied in order for the transistor to act as a linear resistor in the deep tride region, with the resistance being \$\frac{1}{kv_{ov}}\$.

Answer (score 0):

The term in the square bracket is:
$$\small \left[(V_{GS}-V_{TH})V_{DS}-\frac{1}{2}V^2_{DS}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\large \left[\small 2(V_{GS}-V_{TH})-V_{DS}\large \right]\small V_{DS} $$

If $$\small V_{DS}<<2(V_{GS}-V_{TH}) $$

We can ignore \$\small V_{DS}\$ in the right-side square brackets, hence:

$$\small \frac{1}{2}\left [2(V_{GS}-V_{TH})-V_{DS}\right]V_{DS}= (V_{GS}-V_{TH})V_{DS}$$